# Custom entity spanning multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework

I am in desperate need of some EF expert advice. How would you create custom entities than span multiple tables in a DDD? From what I know, there are 3 possible solutions:

1. create custom entity in the model and add DefiningQuery for it, which acts as a view into that entity, essentialy joining multiple tables in pure SQL,
2. create a custom entity as POCO class that has other entities as its properties. When querying with LINQ, project data that you need into an anonymous object first, then to that custom entity,
3. create a view in DB that spans multiple tables and add that to a model

The first option would create a dependency on a particular data source implementation (Oracle), since we would need to write Oracle complaint SQL queries.

Custom objects in the second solution are defined outside a model and TBH, is the one that I like the most and cannot see any real pitfalls with it, apart from someone having to understand LINQ :)

Third option would mean creating lots of DB views, which I am not sure our DBA would be too happy about.

Please share your opinion which solution sounds more reasonable to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your database tables has correctly configured one-to-one relation you can use [entity splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/). Without one-to-one relation your table spanning is not deterministic from EF perspective.

In addition to your mentioned options you can also try to use [QueryView](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/12/queryview-element-in-entity-framework.aspx) - ESQL query mapped to your custom POCO inside EDMX file. It is like combination of the first and second option hidden inside mapping (independent on storage). The problem is that QueryView supports only subset of ESQL so it really depends what you want to map.